# Winforms event when a mouse leaves a control

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls

I have a user control that's overlaid over other controls. A button brings it up and I want it to hide (`Visible = false`) when the mouse leaves it. What event should I use? I tried `Leave`, but that only fires after I manually hide it. I also thought about `MouseLeave`, but that's fired never.

EDIT: The control consists of a `ListView` and a `Panel` with a bunch of buttons in it. They are docked straight in the control, with no top-level container.

Comment: `MouseLeave` should work, could you post your code? Are you sure you know how to register some handler for the `MouseLeave` event? Could you talk a little more about the `layout` of your controls especially your `UserControl`.

Comment: Added control overwiew. The event handler is added using the VS designer, it shouldn't be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`UserControl` is in fact a panel holding some controls on it for convenience and easy re-use (it has advantage of design time support). In fact when you move your mouse out of the `UserControl`, one of its child control fires the `MouseLeave`, not the `UserControl` itself. I think you have to implement some `Application-wide MouseLeave` for your `UserControl` like this:

```
public partial class YourUserControl : UserControl, IMessageFilter {
  public YourUserControl(){
    InitializeComponent();
    Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
  }
  bool entered;
  public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == 0x2a3 && entered) return true;//discard the default MouseLeave inside         
    if (m.Msg == 0x200) {                
      Control c = Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd);
      if (Contains(c) || c == this) {                    
         if (!entered) {
            OnMouseEnter(EventArgs.Empty);
            entered = true;                  
          }                   
      } else if (entered) {
         OnMouseLeave(EventArgs.Empty);
         entered = false;                    
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```